# Why does this php single checkbox value not showing in my email sender?

Tags: php, email, checkbox

I would like to know why can't I receive the check-box value in my PHP email sender?

Here is the html:

```
<form method="post" action="send.php" name="cform" id="cform" class="form-signin" role="form">
    <input name="name" id="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your name and surname..." >
    <input name="email" id="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your email address..." >
    <textarea name="comments" id="comments" class="form-control" placeholder="Your request..."></textarea>
    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" id="newsletter" value="Yes" checked>    
        <span>I would like to receive the newsletter</span>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="lightButton" value="Submit >">
    <div id="simple-msg"></div>
</form>
```

And here's the relevant part of the PHP code I found on the Internet ( don't know if here or in a blog, I'm kind of new to PHP so I can't do it from scratch ) and modified to my needs.

```
<?php

if(!$_POST) exit;

if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

$name           = $_POST['name'];
$email          = $_POST['email'];
$comments       = $_POST['comments'];
$x_newsletter   = $_POST['newsletter'];

$address = "xxx@gmail.com";
$e_subject = 'Richiesta contatto da ' . $name . '.';
$e_body = "Richiesta contatto da parte di $name:" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_content = "\"$comments\"" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_checkNl = "Inviare newsletter: $x_newsletter" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_reply = "$name\n$email";

$msg = wordwrap( $e_body . $e_content . $e_checkNl . $x_newsletter . $e_reply, 70 );

$headers = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;

?>
```

I put the $x_newsletter variable to catch the check-box "Yes" value (or at least something like 0 or 1), and later in the code a $e_checkNl that would write the value in the mail.

Fact is that it is a week that I'm searching in stack-overflow for and answer and troubleshooting this PHP trying to figure this thing out but every email I receive from the PHP sender lacks of this important information.

I don't really know, it could be a typo, or some sort of syntax that I can't manage as a newbie, but it's driving me crazy.

Can you please help me?
I'm here should you need any other kind of information.

Thank you,

Nico

**EDIT:**

here is the full PHP page. Every "if" i put I always get a "NO" option that is totally weird...

```
<?php

if(!$_POST) exit;

// Email address verification, do not edit.
function isEmail($email) {
return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i",$email));
}

if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");
print_r($_POST);
$name       = $_POST['name'];
$email      = $_POST['email'];
$comments   = $_POST['comments'];
$x_newsletter   = $_POST['newsletter'];

if(trim($name) == '') {
echo '<div class="error_message">Your name is required</div>';
exit();
} else if(trim($email) == '') {
echo '<div class="error_message">Insert valid email address</div>';
exit();
} else if(!isEmail($email)) {
echo '<div class="error_message">Invalid email address. Please retry.    </div>';
exit();
}

if(trim($comments) == '') {
echo '<div class="error_message">Insert your messagge.</div>';
exit();
}

if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
$comments = stripslashes($comments);
}

$address = "xxx@gmail.com";
$e_subject = 'Richiesta contatto da ' . $name . '.';


$e_body = "Richiesta contatto da parte di $name:" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_content = "\"$comments\"" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;

//checkbox
$e_checkNl = "Inviare newsletter: $x_newsletter" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;

$e_reply = "$name\n$email";

$msg = wordwrap( $e_body . $e_content . $e_checkNl . $x_newsletter .     $e_reply, 70 );

$headers = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;

if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {

// Email has sent successfully, echo a success page.

echo "<fieldset>";
echo "<div id='success_page'>";
echo "<h3>Request sent successfully</h3>";
echo "<p>Dear <strong>$name</strong>, Your request has been received, we will contact you as soon as possible.</p><p>Grazie,<br/>Top Italy Travel.</p>";
echo "<p>$e_checkNl</p>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</fieldset>";


} else {

echo 'ERRORE!';

}
```

But the last part makes the form show a div on page for successful or error request, while the first part is a simple form check.

I doubt those cause this issue.

Comment: You do realize that a checkbox that is not checked wont even be sent to the server?

Comment: Meaning: if the checkbox is checked and you send the form then the value will be passed and otherwise you will actually get a notice when you try to access the value of the checkbox like this: `$_POST['newsletter']` but since most people always deactivate notices, they don't see stuff like that...

Comment: To help troubleshoot. Add `print_r($_POST);` before `$name=$_POST['name'];`

Comment: On a side-note, you should definitely put a validate email condition so your emailer doesn't get hijacked.

Comment: On a second side-note, your code works, provided the person keeps that checkbox checked. Likely they are unchecking it when they submit.

Comment: If you want a return of that variable if left unchecked, you can put a hidden field in behind the form with the same name but a blank value. The key will come through then.

Comment: Do this `if(isset($_POST['newsletter'])) {$x_newsletter   = $_POST['newsletter'];} else{ $newsletter="No";}` should they decide to un-check it.

Comment: Another thing, where and how are you using `mail()` or did you leave it out of your code?

Comment: Thanks everyone:
@ITroubs I know that, but a week ago I tried a check like the one posted by @Fred -ii- but everytime I got the "NO" whether I checked or not the check box so I wanted to at least catch the yes value, but I can't.

@dan08 thanks, but when I do that it shows on the page this: `Array ( [name] => test_yes [email] => xxx@libero.it [comments] => test yes pls )` so no newsletter field but why?

@Fred -ii-, thanks, I tried but if I check or deselect the checkbox it shows me always the "NO" option.

@Rasclatt, @Fred -ii- I'm putting the whole php below.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you your desired result:

Replace `$x_newsletter = $_POST['newsletter'];` with:

`$x_newsletter = (isset($_POST['newsletter'])) ? $_POST['newsletter'] : 'No';`

Comment: Thanks dan08, but somehow I always get a NO value, if I check or not the checkbox.

I edited the post so I put the complete php file sender but I don't think it is any different because the other parts manage the sending or the errors in the form